# Return mask from numpy isin function in 1 dimension

Tags: python, numpy, isin

I am trying to use numpy's function isin to return a mask for a given query. For example, let's say I want to get a mask for element 2.1 in the numpy array below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [
        ["1", "1.1"],
        ["1", "1.2"],
        ["2", "2.1"],
        ["2", "2.2"],
        ["2.1", "2.1.1"],
        ["2.1", "2.1.2"],
        ["2.2", "2.2.1"],
        ["2.2", "2.2.2"],
    ]
)
```

I am querying it with the parameters `np.isin(a, "2.1")`, but this returns another 2D array instead of a 1D mask:

```
[[False False]
 [False False]
 [False  True]
 [False False]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]
 [False False]
 [False False]]
```

I was expecting it would return something like:

```
[False False True False True True False False]
```

What am I supposed to do to fix this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rows that "2.1" appears in `a`, you want the `any` method on axis:

```
>>> np.isin(a, "2.1").any(axis=1)
array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False])
```

If you want the indexes of where "2.1" appears in `a`, you could use `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where(np.isin(a, "2.1"))
(array([2, 4, 5], dtype=int64), array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int64))
```